# How to log in to BackTrack Linux?

Tags: login, gui, backtrack, squashfs

I've installed BackTrack 5 R3, a security testing distro, onto a USB drive, and I can get it to boot up, but I'm stuck in the BusyBox shell. Everybody says "just log in with username `root` and password `toor`, then type `startx` to launch the GUI, but `startx` reports "command not found". I've tried various commands such as "login" and "sh", but no luck. `sudo` is out of the question, too.

I suspect that I need to mount the system squashfs somehow, but I can't figure out how I'm supposed to do it. I haven't had much experience with SFS's before.

Comment: Daang, what's with all these downvotes?

Comment: +1 not because I would have upvoted otherwise, but to reverse undeserved downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

#### Posssible Fix #1

I found this youtube video that shows how to fix this particular issue. The video is titled: [BackTrack 5 Bootup startx problem fix](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-PTeR0doKAY).

The video outlines the following steps to fix a startx issue (not sure if it's your's or not):

```
fix-splash
rm /root/.kde/cache-root/icon-cache.kcache
rm /root/.kde/cache-root/plasma_theme_Volat­ile.kcache
rm /root/.kde/cache-bt/icon-cache.kcache
rm /root/.kde/cache-bt/plasma_theme_Volatil­e.kcache
```

#### Possible Fix #2

I came across this other post on cyberciti.biz titled:  [Backtrack 5 KDE startx Failed To Load Error and Solution](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/errorstartx-does-not-work-in-backtrack-linux5-kde64bit/). In this particular fix they mention running the following commands:

```
cd /root/.kde/
find . -type f -iname "*.kcache" -delete
```

#### References

- [BT5 KDE 64bit - startx problem - forum post on backtrack-linux.org](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/forums/showthread.php?t=40286)

Comment: Curious, if you're stuck in the busybox shell, then how are you able to type startx?

Comment: The BusyBox shell is like a nerfed version of the "real" shell - I have like 15 commands at my disposal, all of which are just basic Linux utilities. (`cd`, `help`, etc.) Typing `startx` does exactly the same thing as typing `foo` or `lollolllzz` - absolutely nothing.

Comment: Thanks, I know what busybox is, I was confused where you were typing startx, now I know it's in the busybox shell which will never work, given startx is software installed as part of the distro, not part of the busybox shell.